# Перемешивать или помешивать?

Tags: синонимы

Пишу о производстве напитков, какой глагол является более подходящим: перемешивать или помешивать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Смешивать** - результативное действие получения смеси разных ингредиентов. Если речь не о тонкостях технологии, то подойдёт этот глагол.

**Перемешивать** - действие, направленное на достижение однородной консистенции смеси жидких или сыпучих продуктов; может выполняться разными способами (включая встряхивание в шейкере и т. п.).

**Помешивать** - один из ручных способов получения однородной жидкой массы (совершением медленных движений ложкой или иным инструментом в емкости с продуктом).